# Is there any way to capture only 'X' event from modal dialogue using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am having modal dialouge this way,

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
autoOpen: false,
resizable: false,
width: 400,
height: 140,
modal: true, 
buttons: {
  "SUBMIT": function() { 
    $(this).dialog("close");
  }, 
  "CANCEL": function() { 
    $(this).dialog("close");
  } 
},
close: function() {
  alert('close');
}
});
```

And i am trying to get alert('close') once i click x button of the modal dialouge.

But the issue is this alert('close') is being invoked even after submit bitton and cancel button click of my modal '#dialog'.

Is there any way that i can get alert, only on clicking 'X' box of my dialouge and not on clicking sublit or cancel buttons.

However $(this).dialog("close"); should be there in submit and cancel button events.

If i remove $(this).dialog("close"); its working.

I want to get  alert only on clickin 'X' and not on the modal dialouge close.

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll have to get rid of the default close button and add your own, and attach your own handler to that.

Comment: Does it have to be done with `.dialog()` or can you just add a click handler to the `X`?

Comment: @4castle it has to be done with .dialog only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The close() callback will pass an event object which includes a .currentTarget property representing the button which was pressed. You can use that to find out which button was clicked. For example, try something like

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
close: function(event,ui) {
  if($(event.currentTarget).hasClass('ui-dialog-titlebar-close')
  {
     alert('close');
  }
}
```

You could also try directly creating an on("click") function directly on the X button yourself, but that can be a bit flaky.